# Dropbox revisions

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I want to revert 3 files to the version before at the same time. Using the method you see below, works for 1 file, but not for 3:

I call:

```
[[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filename3 limit:10];
```

and then:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedRevisions:(NSArray *)revisions forFile:(NSString *)path{ 

for (DBMetadata *file in revisions) 
{ 
if (segmentSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { 

NSString *title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Folder3"]; 
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager]; 

NSString *destDir = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Folder2"]; 
NSString *filename3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@photofile.png.%ld", destDir, title, (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber]; 


[[self restClient] restoreFile:filename3 toRev:file.rev]; 

[[self restClient] restoreFile:filename4 toRev:file.rev]; 

[[self restClient] restoreFile:filename5 toRev:file.rev]; 

NSLog(@"MetaData's Revisions \t%@", file.rev); 

} 
}
```

Would I have to do:

```
[[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filename1 limit:10];, [[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filename2 limit:10];...
```

Comment: The code looks like you want to restore 3 files to a revision of one file. Each file has it's own revisions, you can't do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was much easier to solve than I thought. I discovered that when you run the code

```
[[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filename1 limit:10];
```

you are passing on the path to.

Solution:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedRevisions:(NSArray *)revisions forFile:(NSString *)path{ 

for (DBMetadata *file in revisions) 
{ 
if (segmentSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { 


[[self restClient] path toRev:file.rev]; 

NSLog(@"MetaData's Revisions \t%@", file.rev); 

} 
}
```

Comment: even if its not reloading the 2-last version